HOW to automate validation testing of user-data
I have several user-data files on an internal gitlab repo.
I am running a deploy job which is deploying the user-data to our internal tftp server.
Our tftp server is part of our netboot.xyz instance. When I try to deploy our user-data via preseed address, it seems the installer picks up our config, but fails with:
DataSourceNoCloud.py[DEBUG]: Seed from https://our-tftp/user-data not supported by DataSourceNoCloud [seed=None] [dsmode=net]

So I thought I create another JOB which is running the validation script of subiquity, which is documented here.
Let's ignore my approaches to get the script running inside a docker container... The deps a straight forward ridiculous for a validation script.
So I installed a bare metal shell gitlab-executor and installed on the machine the deps of the script.
Sadly the response doesn't help at all, so many deps for nothing:
$ ./scripts/validate-autoinstall-user-data.py ../user-data
Could not find path to SNAP
Failure: The provided autoinstall config failed validation

What does that even mean? My user-data has no entry for snap dependencies.
Here is my user-data:
#cloud-config
autoinstall:
  version: 1
  storage:
    layout:
      name: lvm
      sizing-policy: all
  keyboard:
    layout: de
    toggle: null
    variant: ''
  timezone: "Europe/Berlin"
  user-data:
    users:
    - name: admin-user
      passwd: <REMOVED>
      shell: /bin/bash
      lock-passwd: false
      groups: users
  ssh:
    allow-pw: false
    authorized-keys:
      - "ssh-ed25519 <REMOVED>"
      - "ssh-ed25519 <REMOVED>"
    install-server: true
  late-commands:
    - |
      bash <<'EOF'
        source <(cat /run/systemd/netif/leases/* | grep ^HOSTNAME=)
        [[ -n "${HOSTNAME}" ]] && echo "${HOSTNAME}" > /target/etc/hostname
      EOF
      true


Based on the info in the question what does this have to do with Ubuntu?

As far as I know, the company canonical provides ubuntu. Canonical subiquity is the official ubuntu installer. The validation script mentioned here: https://canonical-subiquity.readthedocs-hosted.com/en/latest/howto/autoinstall-validation.html is published by canonical.

This is a volunteer Ubuntu OS support site and has nothing to do with the maker of Ubuntu or any of their other products. Therefore you question is off topic here. You can try the stack exchange site.

Is installing Ubuntu OS not something related to ubuntu? I know that this site is not maintained by canonical.

This question is on topic at Ask Ubuntu. In fact there is currently not even one reviewer vote on this question to close it.

Agree, This is very much on topic

It appears that the validate script needs subiquity-legacy-cloud-init-validate script.  It expects to find this in the following location(s)
server_bin = f"{snap_path}/system_scripts"
desktop_bin = f"{snap_path}/bin/subiquity/system_scripts"

I don't have snap installed on my system however i noticed that the script(s) can be found in the subiquity checkout in the system_scripts subdirectory.  As such you should be able to use the following command to run the validate script
SNAP=. ./scripts/validate-autoinstall-user-data.py ~/autoinstall.yaml


Looked like this issue got introduced in 95ccb9c75322f75a2357c88836ee3fb40a6ffd1e. You may try 9fd3c924791b737d6b6cce04a35e3b82d45b535b as of now.

Hi I think you are speaking about commits, but you did not specify the repo they belong to.

Neel is refereing to the subiquity repo (where you get the validate script from)  https://github.com/canonical/subiquity
